# Delete query that has the very last date in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have a scenario where the record is like this:

**date**

- 2018-01-15
- 2018-01-16

Now what I need to do is just delete the very last date. I need to delete the query that has `2018-01-15`.

My code is like this:

```
public function deletelatDate()
{
    // $datedel = '2018-04-03';
    $datedel = Attendance::sortBy('date', 'desc')->first();

    // $query->sortBy('date', 'desc')->first();
    DB::table('attendances')->where('date', $datedel )->delete();

    return back()->with('success','Last attendance entries successfully deleted'); 
}
```

Do you have any suggestions on how am I able to fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: What is the table name for model `Attendance` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `orderBy` and get column `date` after getting first record

```
 public function deletelatDate()
 {
      $datedel = Attendance::orderBy('date', 'asc')->first();
       DB::table('attendances')->where('date', $datedel->date )->delete();
      return back()->with('success','Last attendance entries successfully deleted'); 
   }
```

Also check success of query before sending success message

Answer (score 2):

You can use `latest` to get the latest record: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

```
public function deleteLatest()
{
    // $datedel = today()->format('Y-m-d');     <-- use today's date
    $datedel = '2018-04-03';

    // find the record to delete 
    $toDelete = Attendance::where('date', $datedel)->oldest('date')->first();

    // only perform delete if a record is found
    if($toDelete) {
        $toDelete->delete();
        return back()->with('success','Last attendance entries successfully deleted'); 
    }

    return back()->with('error', 'No attendance entry found for this date: ' . $datedel);
}
```

Comment: The question is a little vague but I think OP wants oldest, not latest. Also, you can do it in one line instead of getting the row first.

Comment: @HH what should i put in the $datedel?

Comment: Yeah I'm looking for the oldest @JoelHinz

Comment: @gwapo it depends on what date you want to use, you can either pass it as a param `public function deleteLatest($datedel)` or get today's date `$datedel = today()->format('Y-m-d')`

Comment: How to make my $datedel to be the oldest record of date field in my table?

Comment: @gwapo first you get the oldest record `$oldest = Attendance::oldest('date')->first();` then you can see what date is has by accessing `$oldest->date`, but i'm not sure I understand why you need to do this as `->oldest('date')` will get you the oldest, which means you don't need `$datedel`